# Can two UITableViews (from different UIViewControllers) reference the same tableview cell's IBOutlet variables?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have two `UIViewControllers`. ViewController A has a `UITableView` X and in each of the cells, there is an inner `UITableView` Y.

In ViewController B, I have a single `UITableView` Z.

`UITableView`s Y and Z represent the same data, hence I would like to make them have the same cell's class (e.g `FoodTableViewCell`).

What I don't know though, is whether I should do this because when I connect a subview of a prototype cell of tableview Y into the outlet of the `FoodTableViewCell` class, the dot appears on the left side (covering the line's number), indicating a successful connection.

When going to the other view controller and going into the prototype cell of tableview Z in storyboard, if I try to connect the subview to an outlet of the `FoodTableViewCell` class (e.g a `@IBOutlet var name = UILabel!`), the dot is already there, since I connected that outlet to the an identical `UILabel` inside the prototype of tableview Y.

Is there any danger here? Am I safe if I using `weak` in the outlet?

**EDIT:**

For those who wonder why such  a structure, ViewController A shows a list of restaurants  and in each of these restaurants the same food is displayed with different prices. So, for instance, ViewController A shows 5 restaurants (TableView X) nearby each containing Sushi and Temaki (TableView Y) displayed in each of them with their respective prices.
Once the user chooses the restaurant, TableView Y (Sushi and temaki with prices of the chosen restaurant) will be transferred to ViewController B and be showed again as Tableview Z.

Comment: According to me it will still crash if `@IBOutlet` isn't connected properly. But if it's connected properly it will work fine without any danger.

Comment: Yes you can assign same tableCell Class to as many tableviews cell but for each different tableView IBOutlet is to be different for its cell

Comment: Why aren't you using xib for creating `UITableViewCell`? You won't need to create in both UITableView Y and UITableView Z separately.

Comment: @PGDev, I am using xib. I connect a subview (say a label) from the interface builder of the prototype cell of  tableview Y to the FoodTableViewCell subclass. The outlet variable appears with the dot on the left, etc.. My question is regarding of whether I can connect another UILabel from a prototype cell (in interface builder) of  tableview Z to the same outlet that tableview Y's prototype cell already references/is connected to.

Comment: Yes you definitely can. Just make sure that you connect all other outlets as well otherwise it will result in a crash if any other outlet that you are using in `FoodTableViewCell` is not connected.

Comment: I think what you want to do is create a single xib file for the FoodTableViewCell and then in ViewController A manually (in code) register it from the xib for UITableView Y and in ViewController B manually (in code) register it from the same xib for UITableView Z.  That way you only ever have to design the cell once and setup all the IBOutlets once.  Doing this you don't even use prototype cells.